# Exp-decay estimate of Schrodinger equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the equation $Hu=0$ with  $u\in L^2(\Omega)$, where $H=-\Delta+V$ for some bounded continuous function $V$ and $\Omega$ is an un-bounded domain(e.g. $\mathbb R^n$). If $0$ is in discrete spectrum of $H$.  Then it is well-known that $u$ is of exp-decay , i.e. there exists $\delta$ such that $e^{\delta |x|}u\in L^2$. (c.f. B. Simon, [Schrodinger Semigroups](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183549767), Bull. A.M.S., (1982) Vol. 7 (3).)

**Q** Under the above conditions, if we make $\|u\|_{L^2}=1$ and $V$ is bounded , can we have  the following estimate
$$\|e^{\delta|x|}u\|\leq C(\delta),$$
where $C(\delta)$ is some constant depending on $\delta$.
(If necessary, we make an assumption  that $H$ is semi-positive. )

*PS*: If $V>C_0>0$ outside some compact set of $\Omega$, then by Agmon-metric method, one can get such a constant $C(\delta)$.

I am not sure, if it is possible to show such an estimate when dropping the positivity condition of $V$.
Any reference is welcome.

Comment: Can you please be more precise about what $C$ may depend on. The result you quote would give such a $C$ for fixed $V$ and $E$, for some $\delta >0$, so what improvement exactly are you looking for?

Comment: What is $E$? Is $u$ an eigenvector with eigenvalue zero or $E$? In the former case how do you know that zero is an eigenvalue?

Comment: Sorry, $E=0$. Misprint.